# Non-code font looks thin, hard to read

Tags: ide, sublimetext3

I'm running Sublime Text 3 on Debian 9.3.

I recently installed a bunch of packages and ran `apt-get update`.

Now Sublime Text's window fonts look weird. Here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/puvkD.png.

Any idea how I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with FreeType. See if there‘s a new version available or downgrade to the version you used before updating.

Comment: How do I do that?